# I can't log in with local-passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm new in passport and I would like some help. I can't log in after adding local passport to my program. The login page is loaded and is always redirected to itself, and is not taken to the main page even if the login is correct. The registration form is working normally.

**This is my node code**:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from "pg";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";

const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const saltRounds = 10;

app.use(session({
    secret: "TOPSECRET",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const db = new pg.Client({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "connectwave",
    password: "secret",
    port: 5432,
})

db.connect();

let currentId;

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs");
})

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("register.ejs");
})

app.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc");
        const data = result.rows;
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            data: data,
        });  
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
    
})

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
}));

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.emailRegister;
    const password = req.body.passwordRegister;

    try {
        const checkEmail = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [email]);
        if (checkEmail.rows.length > 0) {
            res.render("register.ejs", {
                emailMessage: "Email has already been taken.",
            });
        } else {
            bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error hashing password", err);
                } else {
                    const result = await db.query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *", [email, hash]);
                    const user = result.rows[0];
                    currentId = result.rows[0].id;
                    req.login(user, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            res.redirect("/home");
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.post("/post", async (req, res) => {
    const post = req.body.createpost;
    currentId = currentId;
    try {
      await db.query("INSERT INTO posts (text, user_id) VALUES ($1, $2)", [post, currentId])  
      res.redirect("/home"); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
})

app.post("/text", async (req, res) => {
    const text = req.body.text_post;
    const id = req.body.checkBtn;
    try {
        await db.query("UPDATE posts SET text = $1 WHERE id = $2", [text, id]);
        res.redirect("/home");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})

app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => {  
    const id = req.body.post_id;
    try {
        await db.query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $1",[id]);
        res.redirect("/home"); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
})

passport.use(new Strategy(async function verify(usarname, password, cb) {
    try {
        const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [usarname]);
    
        if (result.rows.length > 0) {

            const user = result.rows[0];
            const hashPassword = user.password;

            bcrypt.compare(password, hashPassword, (err, valid) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error comparing password", err);
                    return cb(err);
                } else {
                    if (valid) {
                        currentId = user.id;
                        return cb(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return cb(null, false);
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            return cb("User not found");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**And this is my login.ejs page** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Connect Wave</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/login.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@4.1.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-login">
        <div class="form-login">
            <h1 class="login-title">Sign in to CW</h1>
            <form action="/login" method="POST">
                <div class="input-required">
                    <input class="email" type="email" name="usarname" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <div class="password-box">
                        <input class="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <i class="ri-eye-off-line login__eye" id="input-icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login-btn">
            </form>
            
            <button class="forgot">Forgot password?</button>
            <div>
                    <p class="signup">Don't have an account? <span class="signup-colored"><a href="/register">Sign up</a></span></p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% if (locals.notPasswordMessage) {%>
        <div class="notPasswordMessage">
            <p><%=notPasswordMessage %></p>
        </div>
    <% } else if (locals.notEmailMessage) {%>
        <div class="notEmailMessage">
            <p><%=notEmailMessage %></p>
        </div>
    <% } %>
    

    <script>
        const emailMessage = document.querySelector(".notEmailMessage")
        const passwordMessage = document.querySelector(".notPasswordMessage")
        const showHiddenPassword = (inputPass, inputIcon) => {
            const input = document.querySelector(inputPass);
            const iconEye = document.getElementById(inputIcon);

            iconEye.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (input.type === "password") {
                    input.type = "text";

                    iconEye.classList.remove("ri-eye-off-line");

                    iconEye.classList.add("ri-eye-line");
                } else {
                    input.type = "password";

                    iconEye.classList.remove("ri-eye-line");

                    iconEye.classList.add("ri-eye-off-line");
                }
            });

        }

        showHiddenPassword(".password", "input-icon");

        setTimeout(function () {
            emailMessage.classList.add("hidden");
        }, 4000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            passwordMessage.classList.add("hidden");
        }, 4000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```